# Copy cell style to other cell with Excel-DNA and C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I'm trying to copy a cell's style to another cell using Excel-DNA library and the copy process will be made through a button from ribbon.

I defined a `public class RibbonController : ExcelRibbon` with:

```
public override string GetCustomUI(string RibbonID)
{
            return $@"
      <customUI xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui'>
      <ribbon>
        <tabs>
          <tab id='tab1' label='my tools'>
            <group id='group1' label='Test'>
              <button id='playBtn' label='Import JSON' onAction='OnButtonPressed'/>
            </group >
          </tab>
        </tabs>
      </ribbon>
    </customUI>";
}
```

and

```
public void OnButtonPressed(IRibbonControl control) 
{
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelFile = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
   Worksheet sheet = excelFile.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
   
    sheet.Cells[2,2].Style = sheet.Cells[1,1].Style;
}
```

The cell from row 1 and column 1, has bold and foreground color.

How do I copy the entire style to cell from row 2 and column 2 ?

Seems that assigning Style property is not enough because the style is not applied.